# What tools/stacks Moncaì will rely on?

Tags: open-source, mono, stack, cloud-hosting

On November, 11th, [Moncaì](http://moncai.com/) has been [announced](http://sinesignal.com/blog/archives/2010/11/11/introducing-moncai/).

The post describes the product as *"a platform as a service(PAAS) cloud solution for .NET/Mono web applications"* which would allow to *"deploy your web applications with ease by using Git or Mercurial by simply issuing a push command"* à la [Heroku](http://heroku.com/).

Beside this, very little is known about the supporting infrastructure.

- [Manos](https://github.com/jacksonh/manos) may be involved ([tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/sinesignal/status/25229638427))
- Maybe CouchDB could also be part through [Ottoman](https://github.com/sinesignal/ottoman) API
- It looks like Redis will also be used ([tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/sinesignal/status/27118632454586369))

What have you been able to gather about the choosen tools (messaging, storage, ...) to support the project ?

Comment: I'd never heard of it: +1 for bringing it to my attention. I'll certainly be watching this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some informations are in [this](http://herdingcode.com/?p=294) podcast.

EDIT: major highlights from podcast:

- deployment of ASP.NET (MVC) applications a lot easier
- very close to what Heroku does, but for ASP.NET
- hosted git or mercurial server for deployment
- custom cloud infrastructure based on posix systems and mono
- option of picking the runtime (mono 2.6 LTS for .NET 3.5 or mono 2.8 for .NET 4.0)
- private beta - testing moncai with ~ 2k people
- fractional computing and billing
- free option for hobbyist and developers with low traffic
- sandboxed security - each user have separate process for his stuff
- you don't have to worry about load or scale
- add-ons for various stuff (batch jobs, ssl, ...)
- plans for ssh to customize the VPSs
- you will be able to choose between various frameworks like ASP.NET (MVC), manos, ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you update your answer with what you've learnt from it?

Answer (score 0):

try asking on http://sinesignal.com/email/support/moncai/com/ , or on their blog http://sinesignal.com/blog/archives/2010/11/11/introducing-moncai/

Comment: I think that would spoil a bit the tracking/gathering of leaked information, wouldn't it ?

Comment: but it would at least gather some official information:)

Comment: Well.. You're right :-) How about requesting some up-to-date information  and edit your answer with the answers you'll be provided with ?

Comment: this post starts to look like the author is too lazy to actually gather the information he needs and keeps asking users to do the research for him... Personally i dont actually care about Moncai, as it seems to be a web framework .NET oriented and i prefer PHP or python for that. I asnwered this question as a simple suggestion...